# AutoHotKey: Press some buttons, type some text, press more buttons

Tags: string, replace, autohotkey

I'm writing up an AutoHotKey script, and I am having a few problems.

This is what I want to do...

- Press the page up button
- Press the home button
- Type "#ifndef CLASS_H"
- Type "#define CLASS_H" on a new line
- Press the page down button
- press the home button
- Type "#endif"

...This is what I came up with, and it failed.

```
:*://cpp/cd::
send {PgUp}
send {Home}
(
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
)
send {PgDn}
send {Home}
(
#endif
)
return
```

Answer (score 1):

`send` converts `#` to WIN keystroke, so you should write {#} instead:

```
:*://cpp/cd::
send {PgUp}
send {Home}
(
{#}ifndef CLASS_H {Enter} {#}define CLASS_H {Enter}
)
Sleep,100 // wait a little if there is no effect
send {PgDn}
send {Home}
(
{#}endif {Enter}
)
return
```

Particularly #d works like WIN+D and shows the desktop.

Comment: This script fixes one problem. The hash tags now print out well.  My only problem now is all the text prints on a single line, and the page down never seems to be pressed.

Comment: send {Enter} where you want new line, but your code with it produces double line, so i wrote it in single line
And about keys not seems to be pressed - put some delay before it